# Create new column by combining others in dictionary/ list format

Tags: python

I have a dataframe like this:

```
    A     B     C     D     E
0         abc                
1   10                       
2               def         123
```

I would like to create a new column F as:

```
       F
0      {"A":null,"B":"abc","C":null,"D":null,"E":null}
1      {"A":"10","B":null,"C":null,"D":null,"E":null}
2      {"A":null,"B":null,"C":"def,"D":null,"E":"123"}
```

I've tried to use the `df.to_dict` but it doesn't work.

Can you please advise, appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: show us your code thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['f'] = df.to_dict(orient='index').values()
```

---

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked but can the "None" value change to "null"?

Comment: `df.replace(np. nan, "null", inplace=True)`